# Access an 'mvc' array in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Heres the following problem im generating an array in C# MVC view and trying to access it in a javascript function.

```
string[] arrayofdetails = new string[count];
```

it contains a list of divs that i want hiding

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    for(int x = 0;x < @count; x++)
    {
        $('#@arrayofdetails[x]').hide();
    } 
    </script>
```

I dont even know if this is possible or if im way off base, javascript newbie.

thanks.

Comment: So `arrayofdetails` is the list of id's of the html `<div>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't interact in that way with C# and JavaScript. I would suggest the following: convert the C# array into a JSON string and assign it to a JavaScript variable; inside your `<script>` parse the array into a valid object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //for debugging purpose use two lines
    var jsonArray = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arrayofdetails ))';
    var arryObj = JSON.parse(jsonArray);

    //alternatively, call "JSON.parse()" directly  
    //var arryObj = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arrayofdetails ))');

    for(int x = 0; x < arryObj.length ; x++)
    {
        $('#' + arryObj[x]).hide();
    } 
</script>
```

NOTE: Since the `Json.Encode` method produces a JSON string, the values of the properties/arrays will almost always be double quoted (e.g. `"myValue"`). Constructs such as `var jsonString = "{ myProperty: "myValue" }";` are illegal in JavaScript. Therefore, the generated JSON string must be wrapped inside single quotes `'`.

Comment: Compilation Error: The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @GrahamHull, try it using the complete name: `var jsonArray = '@Html.Raw(System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(arrayofdetails ))';`;

Comment: @GrahamHull, please not that you must use a single quote `'` and not double quotes `"` in order to make it work, i.e. `var jsonArray = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arrayofdetails ))';`.

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json is referenced already, if i try the other way it says its not part of helper.  Im using .net 4, don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @GrahamHull, please see my edit. There was an editing mistake regarding quotes and double quotes. If the helper is still not found, check if you have a reference to `System.Web.Helpers` and if not, add it to the project.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my system.web.helper to copy to local = true and it now compiles, unfortunately my .hide() method doesnt seem to be working, but i suppose thats a seperate issue for me to figure out! thanks.

Comment: @GrahamHull, in my answer I assume that the `arrayofdetails` contains the ids of your `div`s. You should set a breakpoint inside the `for` loop and inspected in your browser's developer window to see if the produced result is the one you assume.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to mix Razor with Javascript

```
@{
    var arrayofdetails = new []{"one","two","three"};    
}
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
    @foreach (var s in arrayofdetails)
    {                        
        @: console.log('@s');            
        @: document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += '@s <br/>';
    }    
</script>
```